# creating a new AVD in eclipse (android sdk)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

what is the difference, when we create a new avd in eclipse, in choose in the dropdown **CPU/ABI**: `ARM(armeabi-v7a) or choose Intel Atom(x86)`
Because I'm creating some AVDs with differents resolutions in order to emulate the screens of different mobile devices, and I always choose ARM(armeabi-v7a) but I don't know why haha I'd like know the different.
Best regards, Daniel

Comment: You don't need to create multiple instances for each version of emulator. You just go to AVD manager and change its skin (a phone skin or tablet skin).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for some versions, e.g. 4.0.3, you can enable hardware acceleration when using Intel Atom. See [here](http://keyable.blogspot.hk/2012/06/intel-atom-android-ice-cream-sandwich.html).

Comment: Ok, and do you know if is possible emulate speed or gps? thanks friend.

Comment: @DanielGarcia Just use the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: Is difficult configure the use of this perspective? I didn't know about it. Okey, opened this perspective going to Window > Open perspective > DDMS and now, In control emulator, I don't see speed...

Comment: @DanielGarcia I think you'd better use a real device rather than an emulator for this.